# How do I make one command "override" the other in unity/c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a very simple mover in Unity3D using GetKey.
I know this may sound simple but I'm a beginner.
Below is the code. I can see the problem but can't find a way to solve it even though I tried a lot of go-arounds.
Thank you in advance!

I tried changing the code from GetKey to GetKeyDown but it didn't work.

```
void Update()
{
    bool w, a, s, d;
    w = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
    a = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
    s = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S);
    d = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);

    if (w)
    {
        transform.Translate(0.0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    }
    if (a)
    {
        transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    if (s)
    {
        transform.Translate(0.0f, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    }
    if (d)
    {
        transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    }
}
```

Expected that if I'm pressing "A" and then pressed "D", the mover moves to the right (as if I'm only pressing D, since I pressed it last).
Currently, the movement cancels out and it stays in its place.

Comment: From the Unity documentation: "Input.GetKey() Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name." If you are holding both keys down at the same time, then they would cancel each other out as you are holding down a direction of west and east simultaneously. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) You could store a private variable that records the last key pressed and use it on each key press to store the value and then use it in your movement logic.

Comment: You can use `else if` instead than they overule top down -> only the first match apllies

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, you could declare a private variable to store the last key pressed and set it using this Event (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event.KeyboardEvent.html) and then use this variable in your logic of your `Update()` method

Comment: As a player, I have utilized holding more than one key down, even if it's not ideal. I would code defensively for that situation by using `if` and not `if-else`, adding up the result, then applying it once.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got what you want: A new button press should cancel the former one

You could use Coroutines:

```
private void Update()
{
    bool w, a, s, d;
    w = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W);
    a = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A);
    s = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S);
    d = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D);

    if (w)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine (HandleKey(KeyCode.W));
    }
    else if (a)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine (HandleKey(KeyCode.A));
    }
    else if (s)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine (HandleKey(KeyCode.S));
    }
    else if (d)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine (HandleKey(KeyCode.D));
    }
}

private IEnumerator HandeKey(KeyCode code)
{
    Vector3 vector;

    Switch(code)
    {
        case KeyCode.W:
            vector = new Vevtor3(0.0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
            break;


        case KeyCode.A:
            vector = new Vector3(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);

            break;

        case KeyCode.D:
            vector = new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            break;

        case KeyCode.S:
            vector = new Vector3(0.0f, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
            break;
    }

    // Go on while the button stays pressed
    while(Input.GetKey(code))
    {
        transform.Translate(vector);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

---

Or do the same thing without routines:

```
private KeyCode lastKeyPressed;
private Vector3 vector;

private void Update ()
{
    bool w, a, s, d;
    w = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W);
    a = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A);
    s = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S);
    d = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D);  

    if (w)
    {
        lastKeyPressed = KeyCode.W;
        vector = new Vector3(0.0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (a)
    {
        lastKeyPressed = KeyCode.A;
        vector = new Vector3(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (s)
    {
        lastKeyPressed = KeyCode.S;
        vector = new Vector3(0.0f, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (d)
    {
        lastKeyPressed = KeyCode.D;
        vector = new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(lastKeyPressed))
    {
        transform.Translate(vector);
    }
}
```

But I don't like that very much ^^

Comment: This code assumes a strict hierarchy, where S cancels D, D cancels A and A cancels W. I think the OP wants e.g. press and hold S, then press and hold W, direction should be according to W. And then when you release one of the keys? The problem is actually a little more complicated than it looked at first.

Comment: Well the odds that you call GetKeyDown on two buttons at the same time the same frame is quite small. And as far as I understand OP asked for the last pressed button ... he didn't speak about what should happen on releasing one ..

Comment: You're right. I missed you were using `GetKeyDown` to get the last key pressed. The "more complicated" was really about the OPs statement of the problem. I think there are probably a few more requirements they will discover as they work through it.

Answer (score 0):

You could define variables in the object which keep track of which key was pressed first. In this case, we flip these values to true only when that key is pressed *and* the other is not pressed.

Then, we only allow movement in a direction if the other direction isn't being held *or* the other direction was pressed first.

```
private bool WPressedFirst = false;
private bool SPressedFirst = false;
private bool APressedFirst = false;
private bool DPressedFirst = false;

void Update()
{
    bool w, a, s, d;
    w = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
    a = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
    s = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S);
    d = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);

    // if any key isn't being pressed, set its pressedfirst value to false
    if(!w)
    {
        WPressedFirst = false;
    }
    if(!a)
    {
        APressedFirst = false;
    }
    if(!s)
    {
        SPressedFirst = false;
    }
    if(!d)
    {
        DPressedFirst = false;
    }

    // if a key is being pressed AND the other one isn't, set it to pressedfirst true
    if(w && !SPressedFirst)
    {
        WPressedFirst = true;
    }
    if(s && !WPressedFirst)
    {
        SPressedFirst = true;
    }
    if(a && !DPressedFirst)
    {
        APressedFirst = true;
    }
    if(d && !APressedFirst)
    {
        DPressedFirst = true;
    }

    // only allow movement in a direction if it is pressed and the other isn't pressed
    // OR if it is pressed and the other was pressed first.
    if (w && (!s || SPressedFirst))
    {
        transform.Translate(0.0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    }
    if (a && (!d || DPressedFirst))
    {
        transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    if (s && (!w || WPressedFirst))
    {
        transform.Translate(0.0f, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    }
    if (d && (!a || APressedFirst))
    {
        transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    }
}
```